# How to Stop Android Tablet from Remapping Device Axes

Tags: android, vector, orientation, tablet, axes

***I have a very specific problem.***

---

For Android devices whose default orientation is portrait (most phones), the device's axes are oriented like so:

[image: Phone's native portrait orientation]

So, when trying to use vector and matrix math and I need to find the right, up, and out vectors for the device, I can use the following, **which works perfectly**:

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(tempRot, null, gravVals, geoMagVals);
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(tempRot, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X, rot);

Vector right  = new Vector(rot[0], rot[3], rot[6]); // the direction the right side of the phone is pointing
Vector up     = new Vector(rot[1], rot[4], rot[7]); // the direction the top side of the phone is pointing
Vector screen = new Vector(rot[2], rot[5], rot[8]); // the direction the screen is facing
```

---

For Android devices whose default orientation is landscape (such as the Xoom), the device's axes are oriented like so:

[image: Tablet's native landscape orientation]

So to achieve the same vectors I had on the phone, I use the following, **which has problems**:

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(tempRot, null, gravVals, geoMagVals);
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(tempRot, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, rot); // this isn't really doing anything in this case

Vector right  = new Vector(rot[0], rot[3], rot[6]); // the direction the right side of the tablet is pointing
Vector up     = new Vector(rot[1], rot[4], rot[7]); // the direction the top side of the tablet is pointing
Vector screen = new Vector(rot[2], rot[5], rot[8]); // the direction the screen is facing
```

---

So it works fine on the phone, but on the tablet it only works for moving it left-and-right and up-and-down, but when I try to rotate the device, suddenly the data stops making sense.  I believe that it is actually changing the axes of the tablet so that they match the default portrait axes (like a phone) and switching back and forth between the 4 possible orientations depending on how I'm holding the tablet.

My application is locked in landscape mode with the following code in the manifest:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" .... />
```

And the recommended implementation of the method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

I can't understand why the device would still be altering its orientation when I'm explicitly telling it not to.  The application runs in Android 2.2, and the tablet is running 3.0.1, so the "screenSize" flag is not necessary in the manifest (though I tried that and it didn't help either).  When this weird data starts coming in, you would expect that some event methods would be called, but neither "onConfigurationChanged" nor "onWindowAttributesChanged" is being called, and "Display.getRotation()" and "Display.getOrientation()" are both staying at 0 at all times.

Can anyone please tell me how to get the three vectors for where the right of the tablet, the top of the tablet, and the screen of the tablet are pointing?  And how to stop the issues that are being caused by rotating the tablet.

[Here is nVidia's info on the Xoom](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/tegra/docs/tegra_android_accelerometer_v5f.pdf)

Comment: I don't think you can stop it from happening. This was talked about in the "Protips" google IO 2011 video. You can find the relavent section on page 23 of this: http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/events/io/2011/static/presofiles/android_protips_advanced_topics_for_expert_android_app_developers.pdf

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the info, but that seems like a horrible design decision - I can't believe Google thought that was a good idea!  I mean, so what about apps where the screen is locked in portrait or landscape orientation?  There's just no way to get the vectors normally, like the same way you do on phones?